# Laplace 3D equation through variable separation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following equation

$∇^ 2u=0$

$0<x,y,z<\pi$

that satisfies the following conditions

$u(0,y,z)=u(\pi,y,z)=0$
$u(x,0,z)=u(x,\pi,z)=0$
$u(x,y,0)=sin(x)sin^ 3(y)$
$u(x,y,\pi)=0$

I used variable separation method $u(x,y,z)=X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$

Through the method I obtained the following

$∇^ 2u=X''(x)Y(y)Z(z)+X(x)Y''(y)Z(z)+X(x)Y(y)Z''(z)=0$

$\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}+\frac{Z''(z)}{Z(z)}=-\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}$

$-\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=\mu^2, \frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}+\frac{Z''(z)}{Z(z)}=\mu^2$

Then

$-\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}=\lambda^2, \frac{Z''(z)}{Z(z)}-\mu^2=\lambda^2$

Wich have the following solutions

$X(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B_{n}sen(nx)$

$Y(y)=\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty D_{m}sen(my)$

$Z(z)=Fe^{w_{n,m}z}+Ge^{-w_{n,m}z}$

where $w_{n,m}^2=n^2+m^2$

I verefied each solution and it seems they are correct. But I'm having trouble aplying the condition

$Z(\pi)=0$. Can somebody tell me if I'm doing something wrong or how to apply the condition correctly.

Answer (score 2):

When you use separation of variables, you come up with solutions $X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$ of the original equation, and it is those product solutions that you sum to obtain a full solution. It is standard to separate first in the variables for which there are two homogeneous endpoint conditions, because the homogeneous endpoint conditions determine the possible separation parameters. And, that's what you were doing:
$$
             \frac{X''}{X} = -\mu^2,\;\;\; X(0)=0,\;\; X(\pi)=0.
$$
That determines $\mu=n$, for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$, and $X_n(x)=\sin(n x)$. Then the same analysis applies to $y$:
$$
             \frac{Y''}{Y} = -m^2,\;\;\; m=1,2,3,\cdots
$$
with corresponding solutions $Y_m(y)=\sin(my)$. The solution in $Z$ is different:
$$
       \frac{Z''}{Z} = -\frac{X''}{X}-\frac{Y''}{Y}=(n^2+m^2),\;\;\;Z_{n,m}(\pi)=0.
$$
Therefore, $Z_{n,m}$ must be a constant multiple of
$$
              Z_{n,m}(z) = \sinh(\sqrt{n^2+m^2}(\pi-z)).
$$
The separated solutions are $X_n(x)Y_m(y)Z_{n,m}(z)$, and sums of these must be formed to obtain
$$
                    u(x,y,z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}A_{n,m}\sin(n x)\sin(m y)\sinh(\sqrt{n^2+m^2}(\pi-z)).
$$
The constants $A_{n,m}$ must be chosen so that
$$
              \sin(x)\sin^3(y)=u(x,y,0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n,m}\sin(n x)\sin(m y)\sinh(\sqrt{n^2+m^2}\pi).
$$
Therefore $A_{n,m}=0$ for $n\ne 1$; so
$$
                  \sin^3(y) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}A_{1,m}\sin(m\pi y)\sinh(\sqrt{1+m^2}\pi).
$$
There is probably a trigonometric simplification, but brute force gives
$$
              \int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^3(y)\sin(m y)dy = A_{1,m}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^2(my)dy\sinh(\sqrt{1+m^2}\pi)
$$
Therefore,
$$
         u(x,y,z) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sin(x)\frac{\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^3(y)\sin(m y)dy}{\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^2(my)dy}\sin(my)\frac{\sinh(\sqrt{1+m^2}(\pi-z)}{\sinh(\sqrt{1+m^2}\pi)}.
$$